# Am I truly using http2?

Tags: javascript, webpack, http2, code-splitting, react-loadable

I have never setup http2 but I think cloudflare serve request as http2.
However, when I see dev tool water fall it looks like http1. 
Because of the when I just test with http2 testing site it show I am serving http2.

[image]

As you see it kinda fetching 5 or 6 at a time.

Do I need to setup ngnix http2 instead of relying on cloudflare ?
I also added webpack optimization option to allow more requests.

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      maxAsyncRequests: 20,
      maxInitialRequests: 20,
      minChunks: 2,
      chunks: 'all',
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true
        },
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: According to the protocol column, your local resources _are_ being delivered over HTTP/2. If you are going through Cloudflare then resources will be delivered over HTTP/2 from it's caching servers, however if it has to communicate with your origin server and that does not support HTTP/2, then page load will be limited by the slowest connection.

Comment: shouldn't waterfall column should be all in one line ? It seems it fetches 5 and then  fetch more

Comment: No, as it appears that the scripts are being initiated from different sources. Resource 1 is initiated by the page itself. Resources 2, 3, 4 and 5 are initiated by a script 'rock...'. Scripts 6, 7, 8 and 9 are initiated by 'main...'. This means the index is parsed, then rock... (which loads some more scripts) then main... (which loads more scripts). This doesn't look like a problem with HTTP, the gap is probably caused by the time it takes to parse the JavaScript.

Comment: so only way to fix this problem is make main.js small

Comment: Consider why rock... and main.js are pulling in other (blocking) scripts. Can they not all be pulled in by the index document? Take a look here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/blocking-resources

Comment: main.js always had defer which I think it should not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `main...` is calling the later scripts, so presumably the browser doesn’t think it needs to load more than the 5 or 6 resources at a time.

HTTP/2 doesn’t magically fix all performance issues with a site - often there are other limitations on a site, and these may be bigger than the issues with HTTP/1 that HTTP/2 is designed to address.

Comment: is there anyway I can remove number of max load ?

Comment: What do you mean by fixing number of max load? I don’t think you have hit a maximum limit. I think you only need those initial 5-6 resources and by the time it has spotted it needs other resources those initial ones are dealt with. I think you are limited by your JavaScript deciding it needs to load resources rather than by 12 being requested at once and only 6 being fetched at a time.

Comment: do you have experience using react-loadable ?

Comment: Nope. Suggest you run webpagetest.org on the app (if deployed) and then link to that.